# Data transfer speed is less than expected

Tags: wifi, webserver, file-transfer

I am running a server on Kali Linux using a command as follows.

```
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

Adapter connected to this Linux desktop is [this.](https://www.alfa.com.tw/products/awus1900?variant=36473966231624)

And I have a router that has which has 5 GHz (and speed upto 1200Mbps)

And I have a Laptop which shows the speed as [image: shown here]

Now I imagine 780 Mbps is the least speed that can be supported.(All of my devices are in same room)
So I expected a data transfer rate of 700-750 Mbps.
But what I am getting is [image: this]

The following picture is my ping test [image]

Now I tested speed test using iperf3 which is shown as follow [image: here]

which is much below expectation.
I want to know how can I achieve a speed of 750 Mbps?Is there any way to check what is bottlenecking my system.

Thanking you.

Comment: what is your specific question? ... `Can somebody help me what I can do?` has a simple `yes` answer ... it does not ask anything about the problem ... there is more than one question that could be asked here ... which question is yours?

Comment: Sorry for a misleading question.My question is Why am ! not getting speed upto 750 Mbps?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a rather inconsistent way of testing speed.

At this point we can't say whether the problem is latency related, bandwidth related, or perhaps networking is fine, but data transfer on the server from the mass-storage devices is impeded somehow.

I suggest running a bunch of tests so you can home-in on the problem:

- A first test, is to run [`ping`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) and check latency.
- Next, install [`iperf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iperf) on the server and a device you want to run tests with, such as a laptop and see what the results are.

Those tests should also be done from various points in the network: between two WiFi devices, and the wired network the server is connected to.

Please also note, that the limited transfer speed might have a number of reasons, including access to hard drive on your laptop, router configuration, etc.pp.

In essence, you want to find the bottleneck that is limiting the transfer speed, should it be actually the network to blame.

Comment: look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxB86gusH60.His Bandwidth is 937 Mbits/sec.Mine is not even his half.